# WiFi Beacon working as BLE Beacon

Tags: wifi, transmitter, bluetooth-low-energy

I had this idea of a WiFi Beacon that works just as a Bluetooth BLE Beacon. I tinkered around with some DIY Bluetooth beacons, like building my own iBeacon for distance measurements.

But my questions is, would it be possible to build a beacon that uses the same principle as an AP [Beacon Frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_frame) but to send information to other devices?

Is there a way of having 2 wifi modules, one transmitting data constantly and the other one receiving the data without actually establishing a connection?

Comment: almost certainly possible, but shopping questions are not allowed

Comment: ok then let me ask another question. Would it be possible to build a receiver and a transmitter with 2 different wifi capable microcontrollers. One constantly sending data and the other one constantly checking for incoming data, without trying to establish a direct connection to the device?

Comment: well yeah, that's how radio works, there are no direct connections in wi-fi, or even in ethernet. all the direct connections are made up, they're basically social constructs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible to do with WiFi. Proof: there are WiFi sniffer apps in the smartphone app stores that receive and report the SSID of all the access points detected.

But WiFi is not designed to let you piggyback your own data on the beacon. BLE **is** designed to allow a small amount of data of your choice to ride on the beacon advertisements.

Also, BLE is designed to do the beacon transmitting and scanning in a more power-efficient way than WiFi, which could be important in a battery-operated project.